# properties at application level

Tags: java, properties

I am currently having a properties file and I am loading this file in each class where there is a need to get the properties

```
static PropertiesConfiguration config = null;
config = new PropertiesConfiguration("Interface.properties");
```

This is working fine. But I know this is not the efficient way to load properties file multiple times.

Can anyone help me how to create the properties file at application level and create a java file (say *config.java*) + calling the method which returns the property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used this approach to set the properties at application level.

Define a properties file (say *configure.properties*).

Create a java class *Config*:

```
public class Config {
    private static Config instance;
    private PropertiesConfiguration configure;

    private Config() throws ConfigurationException {
        configure = new PropertiesConfiguration("configure.properties");
    }

    public static Config getInstance() {
        if (null == instance) {
            try {
                instance = new Config();
            } catch (ConfigurationException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public PropertiesConfiguration getConfigure() {
        return configure;
    }

    public void setConfig(PropertiesConfiguration configure) {
        this.configure = configure;
    }
}
```

This java class load the properties file at the startup and calls the `getInstance` method to get the value of the property. To get the value of the property anywhere else in the application `import Config` and

```
Config.getInstance().getConfig().getString("property.given.in.properties");
```

Sorry if variable names doesn't make much sense.

Thanks all for your input.

Answer (score 5):

One way to solve this is to utilize the [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). You can have a singleton bean that holds the property instance and then you inject this bean as a dependency to each of your class that needs to access those properties.

One way to implement dependency injection to use the [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/) framework. For instance, you can achieve loading the property file using Spring's [PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html). Then this bean becomes your reference bean for rest of the application. A tutorial on this can be found [here](http://codingbone.wordpress.com/2010/02/28/how-to-load-properties-files-into-spring-and-expose-to-the-java-classes/).

Another choice for you is to load the property file in the constructor of the main entry class or the main method of your application and then pass the object to the classes that needs it. However, this will make your application more tightly coupled and maintenance would be harder in the future.

Another option is to create a singleton class that loads the properties and have a method that returns the values as needed.

Comment: can you able to give me some sample code to load singleton class to load at application level, or some links or tutorial. I tried googling it, got wiered results.

Comment: @user877333 - I recommend you study how the spring IOC works. There are tons of tutorial on it online. If you want to create a singleton class just google "singleton java" and you should find plenty of references (including stackoverflow links).

Answer (score 1):

I just load my properties file in the System Properties:

```
public void loadStreamToSysProperties(InputStream in) throws IOException
{
    Properties p = System.getProperties();
    p.load(in);                
}
```

Then I can get them out of `System.getProperty` where ever I am in the code.
In this example the *InputStream* is a Stream I created from the file name/path.

Comment: One issue with this approach is that system properties can be overwritten by an underlying component (so fails on defensive practices imo). This works though not the way I would do it.